# laravel artisan seed Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel

I get an error when running (in laravel)

```
php artisan migrate --seed
```

I get

```
Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
```

My Users seed table looks like this

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete();

        $users = [
            [
                'firstname' => 'David',
                'surname' => 'Smith',
                'email' => 'foo@gmail.com',
                'created_at' => new DateTime,
                'updated_at' => new DateTime
            ],
            [
                'firstname' => 'Mike',
                'surname' => 'Smith',
                'email' => 'bar@gmail.com',
                'created_at' => new DateTime,
                'updated_at' => new DateTime
            ]
        ];

        DB::table('users')->insert($users);
    }

}
```

Any ideas why artisian/php is complaining?

Comment: interestingly, it only happens on db:seed, and not on a full migration

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same package that Laravel uses https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon for managing dates, to fix that, fill datetime columns with appropriate values:

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete();
        $dt = Carbon::now();
        $dateNow = $dt->toDateTimeString();
        $users = [
            [
                'firstname' => 'David',
                'surname' => 'Smith',
                'email' => 'foo@gmail.com',
                'created_at' => $dateNow,
                'updated_at' => $dateNow
            ],
            [
                'firstname' => 'Mike',
                'surname' => 'Smith',
                'email' => 'bar@gmail.com',
                'created_at' => $dateNow,
                'updated_at' => $dateNow
            ]
        ];

        DB::table('users')->insert($users);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` return time and you need string, so to get time in string format try something like this:

```
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("l dS F Y", $someDate);
$newDate = $newDate->format('d/m/Y');
```

Change formating as you need it.

Answer (score 1):

"New DateTime" does work without a problem in Laravel, apparently something has been added to Laravel that lets it overcome this error.

What I've seen happen, though, is that there are other errors in the Seed data, such as specifying a field that doesn't exist, or specifying two seeds that have different columns, and the "DateTime" error appears by default. Try temporarily removing your created_at and updated_at fields from the seed and Laravel will reveal what the actual problem is.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. It ended up that a field higher up in my input array was spelled wrong, and instead of the seeder class complaining about that upon insert it threw the DateTime exception first.

Answer (score 0):

The `new DateTime()` function works perfectly with laravel make sure that the proper value is set for the table name in app/models/tablename.php

```
protected $table = 'TableName';
```

Another note, the class is always singular and the tables tend to be plural for example
PHP class

```
user.php
```

Table Name

```
Users
```

Lastly make sure that the key in the array is correct

```
'updated_at' vs 'updated_at '<--Note the empty space
```